# Using LINQ to SQL with dynamic table prefix

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I created LINQ to SQL file which represent my database.
The table names in the database are formated like so:

```
[prefix]_tableName
```

and I want the prefix to be dynamic, when I tried to change the TableAttribute in the designer.cs file from:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.isftblprfx_config")]
```

to:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name=String.Format("dbo.{0}_{1}", Server.TablesPrefix, "config")]
```

I got build time error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

There is any solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: For one thing, you spelt String.Format wrong.

Comment: In the code it's fine thanks to the intellisense. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Exsaliver Is the underscore between {0} and {1} deliberate? Also, it is spelled [Prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix) not "perfix" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The exception says it all.

[An attribute is emitted into metadata when you compile your code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfz783fz.aspx),  so its arguments need to be determined at compile time, they can not be changed at runtime. So I expect that your `Server.TablesPrefix` is not a constant or readonly string.

If you want to reuse your context for different databases they should have identical schemas. If you can't change the schemas, maybe t4 templates offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name=String.Fromat("dbo.{0}_{1}", Server.TablesPerfix, "config")]
```

should read

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name=String.Format("dbo.{0}_{1}", Server.TablesPrefix, "config")]
```

Typo's are always the worst enemy :)

Comment: @Exsaliver -  
Was "Perfix" the issue then, or is there still an issue?